# Showing $\zeta(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)>0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

A complex function is analytic if it can be represented by a Taylor Series that is valid in the neighbourhood of any chosen point in the domain of that function.

**Question:** How can we show the Riemann Zeta function, as represented by the series $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$ for $\Re(s)>1$ is analytic?

Can we also show the extended function $\zeta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\eta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>0$ is analytic?

---

**Discussion**

My challenge arises from the fact that the above representations for the Riemann zeta function are Dirichlet series, not power series which would be more amenable to comparisons to a Taylor Series.

Is it better to approach the challenge via the theorem which states that a complex function which is complex-differentiable (Cauchy-Riemann conditions) is also analytic? Would a proof to show the Dirichlet series is complex-differentiable be easier?

Comment: **Hint :** A uniform limit of analytic functions is still analytic.

Comment: hi @TheSilverDoe, thanks for your comment. Sadly I'm self-teaching so don't have the background to understand your hint...